# How do I select multiple rows with Tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have an tensor of probabilities, and I want to select the highest probability per column.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random.normal(mean=0, stddev=1, shape=(5, 4))
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.29182285, -0.30140358, -1.6745052 ,  0.04754949],
       [-0.4013166 ,  0.98574334, -0.33083338, -1.2661675 ],
       [-0.49397126, -0.19175254,  1.4922557 , -0.9857015 ],
       [ 0.57078785,  0.30159777,  0.34956333,  0.17599773],
       [ 1.0847769 , -0.58611375, -0.10727347, -0.13440256]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

I'm trying to select the highest probabilities per column like I would with `numpy` and it doesn't work:

```
x[tf.argmax(x, axis=0), :]
```

> TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got <tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([4, 1, 2, 3])>

What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Convert Tensor to numpy first before using it as matrix

```
x.numpy()[tf.argmax(x, axis=0), :]
```

Comment: sorry. I mean convert x to numpy
x.numpy()[tf.argmax(x, axis=0), :]

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of the question I'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

Today I learned that `tf.gather()` does that.

```
tf.gather(x, tf.argmax(x, axis=0))
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 1.8891758 ,  0.7073202 , -0.78521085, -2.7632885 ],
       [-1.3851309 ,  1.4023514 , -0.9735394 , -0.81982684],
       [-0.22595228, -0.7155944 ,  0.37807527,  2.2081604 ],
       [-0.22595228, -0.7155944 ,  0.37807527,  2.2081604 ]],
      dtype=float32)>
```